# Powerbuilder Syntax for dw string replacement

Tags: excel, powerbuilder, datawindow

I'm currently importing a CSV File but the problem is that this CSV File is extracted from another different program (w/c I do not control). The excel file is saved as CSV but when you open it in text/notepad. It shows as like this ex.

> name;gender;age;address1;address2
>
> Sid;m;100;44 lowave st.;pque vill

it used semi colon not a comma

now i could ask the users to open it in excel and use the delimiter options to make it comma separated but I know they would still ask a way to automate the process.

Now Im getting ready for their soon to be request so I was thinking of importing the excel file to a single column datawindow then parse each row to find a ";" and replace() it by "," in a do while manner, then save it as CSV afterwards.

My question is do i have to replace char per char using While Loop or there is a better way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileReadEx() the file into a string variable, global replace (PFC has a good one if you don't already) the semicolons with tabs, and ImportString(). (Assumes the data has no tabs or semicolons.)

Or read the file, parse it yourself and load with InsertRow() and SetItem().

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: Thanks. so that would be that best way? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Are these files created and consumed by the same locale?  The ; is probably because the CSV was created on a machine with regional settings where the comma is decimal point.  So another option might be to use the Excel ODBC driver to pull the data into the datawindow (haven't tried it :)).

Comment: BTW, be careful with global replace. If a text column happened to contain a ; as data, you many not want to replace it.  In the CSV, that column value will be enclosed in quotes... and then, if the column value ALSO has double quotes in it, those quotes will be escaped with a second double quote.

Comment: Best depends on a lot more than has been revealed here. As I mentioned, this approach will suck if the data has (or ever will have) tabs or semicolons. Jim's Excel ODBC would probably be a great option if only deploying to a couple of workstations you have 100% control over; not so much for 50,000 random consumer workstations. If the delimiter has the risk of changing (e.g. regional settings), maybe an OLE into Excel would be better if you can be assured Excel will be installed. We can't say "best".